# Webbrowser select combobox shows off place

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a web page and a full screen agent form.
In c# I just used the webbrowser to show the page that contains select boxes.

In chrome or ie the list shows fine. But in the agent form the combobox is shown off place.

Is there any options to add to solve this problem?

[image]

The code i used to show the page is this.

```
     string url = $"test";
     webBrowser.Url = new Uri(url);
```

And used this option.

```
webBrowser.ObjectForScripting = this;
```